# If $\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+P(x^2)}\right)dx}+\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(x+1\right)dx}=\frac k{16}(\pi-\ln4)$, find the value of $k$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

> If $\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+P(x^2)}\right)dx}+\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(x+1\right)dx}=\frac k{16}(\pi-\ln4)$, find the value of $k$.

The above question is taken from JEE practice set.

I think there is some error, as it's not clear what $P(x^2)$ is.

If we have to correct the question, can you suggest something? Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming it's an unknown polynomial of $x^2$

Comment: An idea is to start with the following two integrals:
$$\int_0^1 \arctan(x+1)dx=-\frac{1}{4}(\pi-\ln 4+2\ln 5-8\arctan 2) \quad \quad (1)$$
$$\int_0^1 \arctan(x-1)dx=\frac{1}{4}(\pi-\ln 4) \quad \quad (2)$$
Therefore we would like to keep only the second integral (but in the same time to combine it with the first integral which contains $\arctan(x+1)$). The only obvious way to do it is as follows:
$$-(\arctan(x-1) + \arctan(x+1))+\arctan(x+1)=\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2-3}\right)+\arctan(1+x)$$
This gives $k=4$ and $P(x)=x-3$, but good luck proving this is the only solution.

Comment: @Zacky Thanks. And sorry I should have mentioned that the answer given is $k=12$

Comment: In that case, either $p(x)$ itself or its properties should be provided in the question. They would've taught you how to find polynomials by their properties in Applications of Derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar type appeared on my test a while back, The question you have asked is incomplete, here's the complete question and my solution.

> Let P(x) be a polynomial with real coefficients such that
> $$(x^2+x+1)P(x-1)=(x^2-x+1)P(x)$$ for all $x\,\epsilon \,R$ and $P(1)=3$.
> Let
> $$\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+P(x^2)}\right)dx}+\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(x+1\right)dx}=\frac{k}{16}(\pi-ln4)$$
> Find $k$.

$$I=\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+P(x^2)}\right)dx}+\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(x+1\right)dx}$$

Let us begin with the functional equation to get $P(x)$,

$$(x^2+x+1)P(x-1)=(x^2-x+1)P(x)$$

Let, $$P(x)=(x^2+x+1)H(x)\tag1$$ $$P(x-1)=(x^2-x+1)H(x-1)\tag2$$

Substitute $(1)$ and $(2)$ in the functional equation;

(a well known technique done to cancel out factors on either side)

$$(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)H(x-1)=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)H(x)$$

$$H(x-1)=H(x)$$

$$H(x+1)=H(x)$$

This resembles the form $f(x)=f(x+T)$, where $T$ is the fundamental period of $f$.

So $H$ is periodic with period $1$

Previously as assumed $H$ is also another polynomial function and periodic, $H$ has to be a constant function. Let $H$ be denoted as a constant real value $'t'$. We have,

$$P(x)=(x^2+x+1)(t)$$

Put $x=1$, we get $t=1$ and this completes the hurdle of getting $$P(x)=(x^2+x+1)$$

$$I=\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+(x^4+x^2+1)}\right)dx}+\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(x+1\right)dx}$$

$$I=\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)}\right)dx}+\int_0^1{\tan^{-1}\left(x+1\right)dx}$$

$$I=\int_0^1 arctan(x^2+x+1) - arctan(x^2-x+1) + arctan(x+1) \,dx$$

$$I=\int_0^1 arctan\left(\frac{1}{x(x-1)+1}\right) - arctan\left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)+1}\right) + arctan(x+1) \,dx$$

$$I=\int_0^1 arctan(x)-arctan(x-1)- arctan(x+1)+arctan(x)+arctan(x+1)\,dx$$

$$I=\int_0^1 3(arctan(x))\,dx$$

$$I=\frac{3}{4}(\pi-ln4)$$

On comparing, we get $k=12$

.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi. How did you assume $P(x)$ to be $(x^2+x+1)H(x)?$